# How to update states of child from parent component in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a Parent component where I keep getting the updates of the data set to display. Which I have to show continuously in the Bottomsheet if it's open. I am able to send the updated data to the StatefullWidget. Below is the code how I am receiving the live data for every second if the bottomsheet is open.

```
class PositionDetailsModal extends StatefulWidget {
 NetPosition netPosition;
 PositionsState instance;

 PositionDetailsModal({this.instance, this.netPosition}) : super();

 setLatestUpdates(NetPosition netPositionLocal) {
 netPosition = netPositionLocal; 
  if(ApiProvider().positionDetailsModalState != null) {
  log("positionDetailsModalState :" + positionDetailsModalState.toString());
  // Once the State is set inside its init i am storing the instance of it in global field 
  // and calling this method to update the state.
  ApiProvider().positionDetailsModalState.updateChangesToUI(netPositionLocal);
   }
 }
@override
PositionDetailsModalState createState() => PositionDetailsModalState();
}
```

But if I call updateChangesToUI and do setState then I am getting this error

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Is there any way I can update the values in the Bottomsheet as and when there is a data update available in parent class in flutter?